# logcat looping somuch error, android studio newbee

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

Hi guys I am just trying to run a empty app with on log.d for me to see it's log on `onCreate()` method, but the logcat show's a looping of error like this

> 018-10-25 15:33:43.487 887-1041/? E/PROXIMITY: ProximitySensor:
>   unknown event (type=3, code=0)
>
> --------- beginning of system 2018-10-25 15:33:43.623 887-960/? W/PackageManager: checkUidPermission():
>   android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL of 10011 is denied.
>   2018-10-25 15:33:43.623 887-960/? W/PackageManager:
>   checkUidPermission(): android.permission.REAL_GET_TASKS of 10011 is
>   denied. 2018-10-25 15:33:43.627 887-28402/? W/PackageManager:
>   checkUidPermission(): android.permission.REAL_GET_TASKS of 10011 is
>   denied. 2018-10-25 15:33:43.629 887-28400/? W/PackageManager:
>   checkUidPermission(): android.permission.REAL_GET_TASKS of 10011 is
>   denied. 2018-10-25 15:33:43.701 247-247/? I/wmt_launcher: fw log ctrl
>   flag has been set 2018-10-25 15:33:43.701 247-247/? I/wmt_launcher: fw
>   dynamic ctrl flag has been set 2018-10-25 15:33:43.737 887-1041/?
>   D/LIGHT: [ALS]>>en:1,cnt:128,EV_ABS event:code,0;value,50

Comment: you can select log filter by selecting show selected application from filter dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

**onCreate Method**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_activity);

        Log.d("Tag","message");
    }
```